# look ahead in ListView.builder flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using a ListView.builder to display an unknown length of information (chats). I need some way to identify the elements that are not visible to be able to display them in a "More " button on either side.

Example: I have a list of messages as follows:

```
John "xyz"
Doe "xyz"
Matt "xyz"
Daemon "xyz"
Ann "xyz"
```

Let's say the display shows only Doe & Matt. How do I get the chat by John and Daemon so that I could show these as scroll buttons? And if I was at the end (Daemon/Ann) to identify that I was at the end?

Comment: You can implement pagination and use Scrollcontroller to detect the end and pass that controller in ListView.builder

Comment: Fahmida, I've still not figured out how to "look ahead", perhaps you can detail your suggestion more...